# How to set conditional breakpoint on return statement globally?

Tags: c++, gdb, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I have a code full of functions like:

```
bool f_i() 
{
    if (!f_0()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!f_1()) {
        return false;
    } 
    // ...
    if (!f_n()) {
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
// etc...
```

On some step of execution some callee can return `false`, and `false` propagates through all the callers. It is hard to write error messages at the moment (code is rapidly changed). During debugging it is excessive to have error mesages before every `return false;`.

Is it possible to set conditional (condition: say, function return `false`) breakpoint on `return` statment globally, using `GDB`?

Comment: Can you just seperate it into multiple lines and then break on line? `b file.cpp:12`

Comment: @Ben No, I cannot. There are an abundance of a lines, which contains `return false;`.

Comment: I assume it is considerably more complicated than this, as that entire thing devolves to simply `return f1() && f0();`. Regardless, if it came down to it a struct with a `bool` conversion operator and a little torque on the preprocessor would likely work if prodded hard enough (and give you a place to set your breakpoint: on the operator). Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig Nice approach. It will be the last resort.

Comment: There are [AST matchers in **clang++**](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/07/29/ast-matchers-and-clang-refactoring-tools), but I cannot think up how to use it. BTW **GDB** have `rbreak` (utilizes regex) command, but it specialized for function names only.

Comment: @Orient oh its horrifying, but can work in a pinch. [see it live](http://ideone.com/itoDCA). There are obvious cases where it would not work, like `return something();` where `something()` evaluated to `false`, or `return !true;`, etc. But as I said, gritty but may help out if targeted tightly enough. Added to my favs list as I'm interested in seeing this pan out.

Comment: @WhozCraig I can specify `using return_type = boolean_type;` for all the functions as a return type. And define `struct boolean_type { constexpr boolean_type(bool const _value) : value_(_value) { ; } constexpr operator bool () const { return value_; } private : bool value_; };`. Then try to catch a `false` in ctor or conversion operator.

Comment: Maybe is there possibility to catch event: `0xC3` or `0xC2 0x??` instruction executed (i.e `EIP`/`RIP` points on the byte(s)) and `EAX`/`RAX` contains zero? But what to do with inlined functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On some step of execution some callee can return false

As I understand, you want to find the first function which returned `false` inside `f_i()`. You can use [reverse debugging](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord/Tutorial) for this.
You can:

1. finish current frame execution

   (gdb) fin
2. step backwards, if return value is `false`

   (gdb) reverse-step
3. if you need, you can continue to go backwards, deeper into `false` propagation calls

   (gdb) reverse-fin
   (gdb) reverse-step

Comment: The function is not the one. A plenty of similar functions in different translation units.